Empirical approaches for predicting mass spectra
One way of predicting a mass spectrum of a new molecule is to run a semi-empirical BOMD computation where the molecule is ionized, gets a big energy and starts dissociating. However, I suppose that in many cases a better approach is using some empirical knowledge about the molecule.
I have implemented in my program Chemcraft a tool where you can specify the structure of your molecule, then type the position of a peak in your mass spectrum, and the program will enumerate all possible fragment ions which can produce this peak. The current approach is to exclude all rearrangement ions. However, I suppose that the rearrangement ions occur in the mass spectrums quite oftenly. What are the most typical types of rearrangements in the mass spectrum? I know about the McLafferty rearrangement and the migration of the double bond; maybe there are some other such well-known rearrangements?
I am thinking of implementing the following algorithm for checking possible ions. Consider you have this molecule:

The program will enumerate all pairs of bonds, remove these bonds and see possible structures obtained via the re-unition of the fragments. For example, when it removes the C1-C11 and C4-C21 bonds, these recombination fragments will be possible:



I plan to implement the following setting for the fragments enumerator: the users will specify the maximum number of single bonds to be breaked, and the maximum number of non-single bonds (e.g. aromatic) to be breaked. The types of bonds in your molecule can be manually set by the user with Chemcraft. Would such approach be useful for chemists dealing with mass spectrometry?

This question might be better suited to the chemistry exchange. What are other people’s thoughts?

isolated matrix
Sorry, I didn't think about it. Possibly you are right.

But I planned to make a comparison of the empirical and ab initio approaches for this task.

I would think this is actually good for here, but I think the people who would use said tool do not frequently come here.  I personally would think this would be very useful if all common fragments could be identified.  I would want to see a comparison with using CREST + their MS tool though and exactly how wrong the simple approach would be.  Side note: Some sort of chatroom (here or elsewhere) for chemcraft would be great.  Its a great tool the few times I have had to use it.

Tristan Maxson
It is interesting to compare the ab initio and empirical approaches for different tasks, including the mass spectra. I’d like to speculate, that the use of the knowledge of chemistry (especially organic) can be considered as a kind of molecular mechanics computation performed in our brain. I mean all this knowledge about the types of bonds, hybridization and so on. And quite often this “molecular mechanics” works more reliably than a standard routine with ab initio. Do you agree?

@Linkey I understand you are going to make the comparison between empirical and ab initio approaches, but is that what you're asking about, or are you asking about rearrangement reactions and whether or not your program would be useful for chemists?

@isolated matrix, I like to talk on hylywar threads on forums, and in such threads the members often post applied information, so the whole discussion becomes both interesting and useful. Anyway, my initial question here was whether the approach I suggested can be convenient for chemists who work with mass spectrometry.

@Linkey Additional patterns: \alpha cleavage of ketones, potential dehydration of alcohols, retro-(hetero-)Diels-Alder reactions & their fragments, benzyl and allyl cleavage, creation of oxonium/ammonium/phosphonium/sulfonium fragments (onium reactions), losing of CO or CO2/decarboxylation, rearrange tropylium from toluylium $\ce{C7H7^+}$, m/z=149 as indicator of phthalic acid diesters (softeners in polymers [incl. lab ware]), $\ce{HCl^+}$ as marker for chlorinated compounds, etc: you might consider checking structural (library) motifs vs the input structure.

@Linkey References about MS (like Silverstein et al., some here) compile many of them. The caveat: how the molecule is ionized (e.g., hard EI/softer CI, still softer MALDI) affects the fragmentation pattern greatly. Machine Learning (a recent example) can be missleading if trained for other conditions, than then met in the lab. Solutions like this likely focus on EI with 70eV.
